# Ubuntu display hitches after logging in

Tags: 12.04, virtualization

I have installed ubuntu 12.10 in VMware player. Before i log in the display is good but after logging in then the display changes.
[a screenshot of my desktop](http://www.4shared.com/photo/AxA3HNFj/Screenshot_from_2012-12-14_011.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you install VMware tools?
Do you enable 'Accelerate 3D graphics' in the display settings?
Set specify monitor settings in display.
Maximum display resolution : Not 2560x1600, but 1920x1080.